# It is us? It is we?

Tags: pronouns

Which would it be--it is us, or it is we?

"Who is the real culprit? It is us, the ignorant, apathetic people of America."

Or, "Who is the real culprit? It is we, the ignorant, apathetic people of America."

Or plural?

"Who are the real culprits? They are us, the ignorant, apathetic people of America." (Sounds more like the name of a retail store--They R Us.)

Comment: "We have met the enemy and he is us." ---Pogo

Answer (score 3):

You'll find both potentially used, at least in formal usage-- it's essentially a matter of stylistic preference.

In more everyday usage, the most common, natural-sounding option is probably "It's us,..." with the contracted form (in other words, as far as everyday speech is concerned, asking whether "It is we" or "It is us" would be used is a slightly spurious question-- the answer is probably neither).

Answer (score 1):

A crude search of the COCA and the BNC shows that *it is we* is just over nine times more frequent in American English than *it is us*, but only about five and a half times more frequent in British English. There may thus be a certain amount of instability in the use of the first person plural personal pronoun, as indeed there is in all personal pronouns, and in particular in the first person singular.

My intuition is that nominative forms (*I, he, she, we, they*) are preferred when they are postmodified in some way, but that the accusative forms (*me, him, us, them*) are preferred when they are not (*you* and *it* being invariable). On those grounds, it might be advisable to use *It is we* here, and in any case fewer people are likely to object to it.

There, of course, ways of avoiding any difficulty altogether, and you have suggested one of them. Another alternative is something like:

> Who are the real culprits? We are, the ignorant, apathetic people of
>   America.

Comment: That is different to my search. I suspect that your results include a lot of "... it is we're..." or "what it is we did wrong" style of constructions, as that does indeed give 12 *it is us* against 68 *it is we* in the BNC. The 12 "it is us" hits are of the form "Too often it is us, the anxious onlookers" or " because it is us Germans who are today leading the way". If you clean the results by searching for a comma after "it is we" you get only 6 results. Add on a 'the' collocate and it falls to only two.

Comment: I expect you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "Who is the real culprit? It is us, the ignorant, apathetic people of America."

Comment: Why? Do you have reasons for saying that?

Answer (score 0):

The *it* in *it is us* stands for 'the real culprit'. If you drop that back into the sentence, then

> The real culprit is us, the ignorant, apathetic people of America.

is obviously correct and

> The real culprit is we, the ignorant, apathetic people of America.

is obviously not correct.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct, and is explained in a good way too!